# Room: Database Folder and Files no longer generated in WearOS App

Tags: android, android-room, wear-os, android-database

I developed a project on Wear OS, And it worked until two days ago. The room database showed the files, And the folder, And after verifying the program, And whether it ran correctly, I decided to delete the folder and the files in the Wear OS app.

Since I wanted only to have data related to the actual purpose of the app. The problem is after running it again, it no longer generates the folder and files.

Does anyone know how to fix this, please? I have also tried to create another project, But it only generates the database folder, not the file content in the application.

[image]

Comment: Your problem isn't clear to me. Please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I basically added a Room database following the guidelines from the android developer website, It worked, and I could retrieve data. Since the project included in the db wrong data while I was a coding the program (like error strings, sensor names, etc…), I wanted to delete the db and start all over to have only the data that I would actually need for my project. The database I deleted (both the files and folder)  have been deleted in the wearOS device explorer. Please let me know if there is still something unclear

Comment: Yes, I know you are facing some issues, But it doesn't described actual problem., Need some debugging information, like: some error messages.

Comment: Alright, unfortunately I cannot see any errors in regard to the database-related configuration. I think the program does not detect it as linked. The only type of errors that I see are my frontend information and the outputs related to the sensors used throughout my project. Are there other ways to check errors for the database?

Comment: I have just added a screenshot with the errors that I get when I try to run the program, I am still unable to fix the issue

Comment: Ok I will start a bounty, so other will notice, They will try to answer your question...

Comment: Is it read-only database, so you need to retrieve these files, or you create them when adding entries into the database

Comment: Yes, I understand it. I create the entries when my Wear OS is pressing a button (and this successfully worked the first time as I explained in the question post); it is only after I deleted the files that I can no longer access and generate database files in the project or any new project. The first time just to clarify, the database would generate the data and show it in the file afterwards. Now, nothing works on the database side. Hope this clarification helps

Comment: @leddev, I think you will not get any answer... You could ask your question again, with much more detail...

Comment: @Nur thank you very much for letting me know, unfortunately at this point I am not sure if it is a program bug since I followed closely some tutorials and examples and have redone the project as the initial one (so should still generate the db, but does not). I have contacted the manufacturer of the smartwatch since the bug may be system wide (every project I create basically does not generate anymore a SQLite database). I am still waiting for a reply from them, once I get an answer I will update the question and/or add more detail.